# EigenLib) Eigen::Quaterniond * 3.0 not working?

Tags: c++, eigen, quaternions

In C++, how do you multiply Eigen::Quaterniond with a scalar?

```
Eigen::Quaterniond q;
q.setIdentity(); // q can be any quaternion.
Eigen::Quaterniond q_new = q * 3.0;
```

just won't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eigen Quaternions were originally only intended to represent 3D rotations (there had been the idea to make general operations possible: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=560).

To work-around your problem, you can access the coefficients of a quaternion using `.coeffs()`:

```
Eigen::Quaterniond q_new(q.coeffs() * 3.0);
q.coeffs() += q_new.coeffs(); // etc.
```

Comment: But even for 3D rotations, what about slerp? That;s crucial for lots of rotations!